# Can I make a database with Eclipse IDE?

Tags: java, database, eclipse, netbeans

I'm a newbie and learning Java. I was watching a tutorial where the guy was using NetBeans IDE. He made a database using NetBeans, not using phpMyAdmin or XAMP or WAMP.

My question is, can Eclipse IDE do the same? If not, what is the best way to do this? And I'm not trying to make a web related program. I want to make a database for a contacts application.

Comment: Are you expecting an UI for database creation in eclipse similar to Netbeans ?

Comment: Umm... I guess. It's really simple and straightforward in NetBeans, so yeah! :)

Answer (score 1):

Make use of Eclipse SQL Explorer for Oracle,DB2 & MYSQL

http://eclipsesql.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 0):

You can use a hsqldb. All you need is a jar at lib path.
More details are at below link
http://hsqldb.org/web/usagelinks.html